# Why can this ENV not be found when it is defined in one layer using a Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile

When the following Dockerfile:

```
ENV A=123 \
    B=$A
RUN echo $B
```

is run, it results in:

```
Step 2/2 : RUN echo $B
 ---> Running in x

 ---> y
Removing intermediate container z
```

When two `ENV` layers are defined:

```
ENV A=123
ENV B=$A
```

it works:

```
Step 2/2 : RUN echo $B
 ---> Running in x
123
 ---> y
Removing intermediate container z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ENV` keyword will be translated to `export` command (builin of the shell usually), if you remove the multi-line declaration you end up with this equivalent:

```
export A=123 B=$A
```

What happens here is that when the shell parse the line to give it to `export` input, `A` is not yet exported and available as an environment variable.

Step by step this will give:

- You type `export A=123 B=$A`
- The shell parse the line and pass `A=123 B=` to `export`'s stdin
- `export` parse each argument in the form `key=value` and as such export `A` to be `123` and `B` to be empty

On the second form, A is available to the shell when the line is parsed, and as such the resulting `export`'s stdin is `B=123`

Answer (score 0):

```
ENV abc=hello
ENV abc=bye def=$abc
ENV ghi=$abc
```

will result in def having a value of hello, not bye. However, ghi will have a value of bye because it is not part of the same command that set abc to bye.